Verifying set emptiness with FindInstance versus Reduce
I have a semialgebraic set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that I believe to be empty.  FindInstance claims that it is empty in less than ten seconds.  But Reduce has run for a week without visible progress --- and might run for decades.  How much trust should I place in FindInstance?  Is FindInstance doing a cylindrical algebraic decomposition, as Reduce claims to do?  If so, why is Reduce so much slower, on the same problem with the same variable order?  Can FindInstance justify its claim of emptiness, perhaps with some kind of certifiable proof?
I realize that computing a cylindrical algebraic decomposition is doubly exponential in the number of variables, so Mathematica's assistance on my problem may be a lot to ask.  I have a polynomial in four real variables of total degree twelve with 437 terms whose coefficients are integers with at most four digits.  I believe that this polynomial's values are always nonnegative when the four variables are constrained by eight simple inequalities.  If that is true, it will justify a theorem in a geometry paper about the Gaussian curvatures of the moduli spaces of quadrilaterals in 3-space whose edges have fixed lengths (those moduli spaces, aka configuration spaces, being 2-dimensional).  Should I view FindInstance's claim of emptiness as a proof of that theorem?
In response to comments, here is my problem in detail; first, here is the complicated polynomial:
poly = 2 - 8  b + 21  b^2 - 36  b^3 + 41  b^4 - 60  b^5 + 107  b^6 - 124  b^7 + 81  b^8 - 28  b^9 + 4  b^10 - 16  c + 82  b  c - 214  b^2  c + 336  b^3  c - 428  b^4  c + 670  b^5  c - 990  b^6  c + 908  b^7  c - 408  b^8  c + 52  b^9  c + 8  b^10  c + 65  c^2 - 376  b  c^2 + 955  b^2  c^2 - 1432  b^3  c^2 + 1965  b^4  c^2 - 3060  b^5  c^2 + 3725  b^6  c^2 - 2392  b^7  c^2 + 454  b^8  c^2 + 92  b^9  c^2 + 4  b^10  c^2 - 174  c^3 + 1026  b  c^3 - 2416  b^2  c^3 + 3588  b^3  c^3 - 5174  b^4  c^3 + 7574  b^5  c^3 - 6916  b^6  c^3 + 2104  b^7  c^3 + 312  b^8  c^3 + 12  b^9  c^3 + 332  c^4 - 1772  b  c^4 + 3855  b^2  c^4 - 5660  b^3  c^4 + 8607  b^4  c^4 - 10828  b^5  c^4 + 5181  b^6  c^4 + 404  b^7  c^4 + 9  b^8  c^4 - 436  c^5 + 1986  b  c^5 - 3902  b^2  c^5 + 5840  b^3  c^5 - 9472  b^4  c^5 + 7058  b^5  c^5 + 18  b^6  c^5 - 4  b^7  c^5 + 373  c^6 - 1404  b  c^6 + 2329  b^2  c^6 - 4416  b^3  c^6 + 5367  b^4  c^6 - 452  b^5  c^6 - 5  b^6  c^6 - 198  c^7 + 514  b  c^7 - 860  b^2  c^7 + 2084  b^3  c^7 - 446  b^4  c^7 - 6  b^5  c^7 + 60  c^8 - 24  b  c^8 + 272  b^2  c^8 - 168  b^3  c^8 - 12  b^4  c^8 - 8  c^9 - 24  b  c^9 - 24  b^2  c^9 - 8  b^3  c^9 - 3  P + 6  b  P - 6  b^2  P + 4  b^3  P + 12  b^4  P - 24  b^5  P + 6  b^6  P + 12  b^7  P - 9  b^8  P + 2  b^9  P + 24  c  P - 54  b  c  P + 52  b^2  c  P + 28  b^3  c  P - 144  b^4  c  P + 108  b^5  c  P + 36  b^6  c  P - 84  b^7  c  P + 32  b^8  c  P + 2  b^9  c  P - 87  c^2  P + 212  b  c^2  P - 108  b^2  c^2  P - 300  b^3  c^2  P + 438  b^4  c^2  P - 84  b^5  c^2  P - 252  b^6  c^2  P + 172  b^7  c^2  P + 9  b^8  c^2  P + 188  c^3  P - 420  b  c^3  P - 60  b^2  c^3  P + 772  b^3  c^3  P - 492  b^4  c^3  P - 300  b^5  c^3  P + 428  b^6  c^3  P + 12  b^7  c^3  P - 254  c^4  P + 408  b  c^4  P + 418  b^2  c^4  P - 848  b^3  c^4  P - 42  b^4  c^4  P + 568  b^5  c^4  P + 6  b^6  c^4  P + 204  c^5  P - 148  b  c^5  P - 504  b^2  c^5  P + 264  b^3  c^5  P + 428  b^4  c^5  P + 12  b^5  c^5  P - 88  c^6  P - 48  b  c^6  P + 192  b^2  c^6  P + 176  b^3  c^6  P + 24  b^4  c^6  P + 16  c^7  P + 48  b  c^7  P + 48  b^2  c^7  P + 16  b^3  c^7  P + P^2 - 3  b^2  P^2 + 3  b^4  P^2 - b^6  P^2 - 8  c  P^2 - 6  b  c  P^2 + 18  b^2  c  P^2 + 12  b^3  c  P^2 - 12  b^4  c  P^2 - 6  b^5  c  P^2 + 2  b^6  c  P^2 + 25  c^2  P^2 + 36  b  c^2  P^2 - 27  b^2  c^2  P^2 - 48  b^3  c^2  P^2 + 3  b^4  c^2  P^2 + 12  b^5  c^2  P^2 - b^6  c^2  P^2 - 38  c^3  P^2 - 78  b  c^3  P^2 - 12  b^2  c^3  P^2 + 52  b^3  c^3  P^2 + 18  b^4  c^3  P^2 - 6  b^5  c^3  P^2 + 28  c^4  P^2 + 72  b  c^4  P^2 + 48  b^2  c^4  P^2 - 8  b^3  c^4  P^2 - 12  b^4  c^4  P^2 - 8  c^5  P^2 - 24  b  c^5  P^2 - 24  b^2  c^5  P^2 - 8  b^3  c^5  P^2 - 7  Q + 28  b  Q - 74  b^2  Q + 128  b^3  Q - 187  b^4  Q + 236  b^5  Q - 196  b^6  Q + 88  b^7  Q - 16  b^8  Q + 42  c  Q - 232  b  c  Q + 608  b^2  c  Q - 1100  b^3  c  Q + 1542  b^4  c  Q - 1580  b^5  c  Q + 920  b^6  c  Q - 152  b^7  c  Q - 32  b^8  c  Q - 137  c^2  Q + 832  b  c^2  Q - 2330  b^2  c^2  Q + 4096  b^3  c^2  Q - 5029  b^4  c^2  Q + 3840  b^5  c^2  Q - 896  b^6  c^2  Q - 280  b^7  c^2  Q - 16  b^8  c^2  Q + 296  c^3  Q - 1884  b  c^3  Q + 5172  b^2  c^3  Q - 8300  b^3  c^3  Q + 8268  b^4  c^3  Q - 2912  b^5  c^3  Q - 760  b^6  c^3  Q - 40  b^7  c^3  Q - 481  c^4  Q + 2876  b  c^4  Q - 7134  b^2  c^4  Q + 9928  b^3  c^4  Q - 5389  b^4  c^4  Q - 876  b^5  c^4  Q - 28  b^6  c^4  Q + 578  c^5  Q - 2928  b  c^5  Q + 6400  b^2  c^5  Q - 5644  b^3  c^5  Q - 178  b^4  c^5  Q + 12  b^5  c^5  Q - 463  c^6  Q + 2016  b  c^6  Q - 3174  b^2  c^6  Q + 504  b^3  c^6  Q + 13  b^4  c^6  Q + 228  c^7  Q - 852  b  c^7  Q + 460  b^2  c^7  Q + 4  b^3  c^7  Q - 64  c^8  Q + 136  b  c^8  Q + 8  b^2  c^8  Q + 8  c^9  Q + 8  b  c^9  Q + 10  P  Q - 20  b  P  Q + 32  b^2  P  Q - 32  b^3  P  Q + 26  b^4  P  Q - 36  b^5  P  Q + 28  b^6  P  Q - 8  b^7  P  Q - 60  c  P  Q + 164  b  c  P  Q - 224  b^2  c  P  Q + 200  b^3  c  P  Q - 212  b^4  c  P  Q + 204  b^5  c  P  Q - 96  b^6  c  P  Q - 8  b^7  c  P  Q + 172  c^2  P  Q - 532  b  c^2  P  Q + 668  b^2  c^2  P  Q - 552  b^3  c^2  P  Q + 612  b^4  c^2  P  Q - 372  b^5  c^2  P  Q - 28  b^6  c^2  P  Q - 300  c^3  P  Q + 940  b  c^3  P  Q - 1000  b^2  c^3  P  Q + 904  b^3  c^3  P  Q - 732  b^4  c^3  P  Q - 36  b^5  c^3  P  Q + 346  c^4  P  Q - 912  b  c^4  P  Q + 884  b^2  c^4  P  Q - 752  b^3  c^4  P  Q - 14  b^4  c^4  P  Q - 248  c^5  P  Q + 472  b  c^5  P  Q - 440  b^2  c^5  P  Q - 8  b^3  c^5  P  Q + 96  c^6  P  Q - 112  b  c^6  P  Q - 16  b^2  c^6  P  Q - 16  c^7  P  Q - 16  b  c^7  P  Q - 3  P^2  Q + 2  b^2  P^2  Q + b^4  P^2  Q + 18  c  P^2  Q + 4  b  c  P^2  Q - 8  b^2  c  P^2  Q + 4  b^3  c  P^2  Q - 2  b^4  c  P^2  Q - 43  c^2  P^2  Q - 16  b  c^2  P^2  Q + 18  b^2  c^2  P^2  Q - 8  b^3  c^2  P^2  Q + b^4  c^2  P^2  Q + 52  c^3  P^2  Q + 28  b  c^3  P^2  Q - 20  b^2  c^3  P^2  Q + 4  b^3  c^3  P^2  Q - 32  c^4  P^2  Q - 24  b  c^4  P^2  Q + 8  b^2  c^4  P^2  Q + 8  c^5  P^2  Q + 8  b  c^5  P^2  Q + 9  Q^2 - 36  b  Q^2 + 85  b^2  Q^2 - 132  b^3  Q^2 + 150  b^4  Q^2 - 96  b^5  Q^2 + 24  b^6  Q^2 - 36  c  Q^2 + 206  b  c  Q^2 - 498  b^2  c  Q^2 + 724  b^3  c  Q^2 - 616  b^4  c  Q^2 + 144  b^5  c  Q^2 + 48  b^6  c  Q^2 + 85  c^2  Q^2 - 492  b  c^2  Q^2 + 1187  b^2  c^2  Q^2 - 1496  b^3  c^2  Q^2 + 428  b^4  c^2  Q^2 + 288  b^5  c^2  Q^2 + 24  b^6  c^2  Q^2 - 126  c^3  Q^2 + 694  b  c^3  Q^2 - 1548  b^2  c^3  Q^2 + 760  b^3  c^3  Q^2 + 584  b^4  c^3  Q^2 + 48  b^5  c^3  Q^2 + 135  c^4  Q^2 - 700  b  c^4  Q^2 + 707  b^2  c^4  Q^2 + 540  b^3  c^4  Q^2 + 30  b^4  c^4  Q^2 - 128  c^5  Q^2 + 378  b  c^5  Q^2 + 174  b^2  c^5  Q^2 - 12  b^3  c^5  Q^2 + 87  c^6  Q^2 - 52  b  c^6  Q^2 - 11  b^2  c^6  Q^2 - 30  c^7  Q^2 + 2  b  c^7  Q^2 + 4  c^8  Q^2 - 12  P  Q^2 + 24  b  P  Q^2 - 38  b^2  P  Q^2 + 36  b^3  P  Q^2 - 30  b^4  P  Q^2 + 12  b^5  P  Q^2 + 48  c  P  Q^2 - 148  b  c  P  Q^2 + 188  b^2  c  P  Q^2 - 156  b^3  c  P  Q^2 + 96  b^4  c  P  Q^2 + 12  b^5  c  P  Q^2 - 98  c^2  P  Q^2 + 316  b  c^2  P  Q^2 - 372  b^2  c^2  P  Q^2 + 228  b^3  c^2  P  Q^2 + 30  b^4  c^2  P  Q^2 + 116  c^3  P  Q^2 - 348  b  c^3  P  Q^2 + 308  b^2  c^3  P  Q^2 + 36  b^3  c^3  P  Q^2 - 90  c^4  P  Q^2 + 184  b  c^4  P  Q^2 + 10  b^2  c^4  P  Q^2 + 44  c^5  P  Q^2 - 4  b  c^5  P  Q^2 - 8  c^6  P  Q^2 + 3  P^2  Q^2 + b^2  P^2  Q^2 - 12  c  P^2  Q^2 + 2  b  c  P^2  Q^2 - 2  b^2  c  P^2  Q^2 + 19  c^2  P^2  Q^2 - 4  b  c^2  P^2  Q^2 + b^2  c^2  P^2  Q^2 - 14  c^3  P^2  Q^2 + 2  b  c^3  P^2  Q^2 + 4  c^4  P^2  Q^2 - 5  Q^3 + 20  b  Q^3 - 36  b^2  Q^3 + 40  b^3  Q^3 - 16  b^4  Q^3 + 10  c  Q^3 - 52  b  c  Q^3 + 104  b^2  c  Q^3 - 40  b^3  c  Q^3 - 32  b^4  c  Q^3 - 11  c^2  Q^3 + 48  b  c^2  Q^3 + 16  b^2  c^2  Q^3 - 104  b^3  c^2  Q^3 - 16  b^4  c^2  Q^3 + 4  c^3  Q^3 + 48  b  c^3  Q^3 - 136  b^2  c^3  Q^3 - 24  b^3  c^3  Q^3 + 13  c^4  Q^3 - 68  b  c^4  Q^3 - 12  b^2  c^4  Q^3 - 14  c^5  Q^3 + 4  b  c^5  Q^3 + 3  c^6  Q^3 + 6  P  Q^3 - 12  b  P  Q^3 + 12  b^2  P  Q^3 - 8  b^3  P  Q^3 - 12  c  P  Q^3 + 36  b  c  P  Q^3 - 32  b^2  c  P  Q^3 - 8  b^3  c  P  Q^3 + 12  c^2  P  Q^3 - 28  b  c^2  P  Q^3 - 12  b^2  c^2  P  Q^3 - 4  c^3  P  Q^3 - 12  b  c^3  P  Q^3 - 2  c^4  P  Q^3 - P^2  Q^3 + 2  c  P^2  Q^3 - c^2  P^2  Q^3 + Q^4 - 4  b  Q^4 + 4  b^2  Q^4 - 4  b  c  Q^4 + 8  b^2  c  Q^4 - 2  c^2  Q^4 + 4  b  c^2  Q^4 + 4  b^2  c^2  Q^4 + 4  b  c^3  Q^4 + c^4  Q^4 - P  Q^4 + 2  b  P  Q^4 + 2  b  c  P  Q^4 + c^2  P  Q^4

The variables b and c are two of the edge lengths of the quadrilateral, while P and Q specify a point in the resulting moduli space.
Here are the eight simple inequalities:
reg = 0 <= b <= c <= 1 && 1 <= b + c && 
  (1 - c)^2 <= P <= (2 b + c - 1)^2 &&
  (1 - b)^2 <= Q <= (b + 2 c - 1)^2

This call to FindInstance returns the empty list in under 10 seconds:
Timing[FindInstance[reg && poly < 0, {P, Q, b, c}, Reals]]

But the analogous call to Reduce runs for more than a week:
Timing[Reduce[reg && poly < 0, {P, Q, b, c}, Reals]]


It's not clear what exactly you did with those functions. In any case, I wonder if perhaps Minimize would finish faster than Reduce?

This is empty talk without "a semialgebraic set in $\mathbb R ^4$".

In my experience, FindInstance sometimes fails to find any solution when solutions actually exist.

Also if you could provide the actual code that would help in terms of investigating possible alternative approaches to attacking the problem. From the description it should not be prohibitively large (and if you think it is too large to post, maybe place it somewhere accessible via a link).

Trying Minimize rather than Reduce is a clever idea; but early indications are that Minimize will also run for a long time.

Did you try CylindricalDecomposition[ ] on Mathematica? What was the result?

I put the long poly on one line, since I don't think we need to read it, just copy it. I think I was careful not to change it, but you may want to check.

LeafCount /@ {poly, poly // Simplify, poly // FullSimplify} suggests that you should start by simplifying the poly

Since FindInstance doesn't find any instances where my complicated polynomial has gone negative, I hoped that Mathematica had actually proved that no such instances exist.  But it now seems clear that my hope was naive.
Reduce, Minimize, and CylindricalDecomposition all run for days on my 4-variable problem.  This indicates that it is already well beyond what Mathematica can analyze in practice --- I have already fallen off of the doubly-exponential performance cliff.
The speed with which FindInstance fails to find any instances strongly suggests that this failure is a quirk of FindInstance.  So that failure provides essentially no evidence about whether such instances actually exist.

It does appear to be a computationally challenging problem. I didn’t let computations go for days but it was clear that nothing I tried was in a hurry to complete.
